# $\mathbb Q[e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}] \cong\mathbb Q[x]/(x^2+x+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I want to show that the field $\mathbb Q[e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}] $ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^2+x+1)$. Can someone give me a hint to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use the first isomorphism theorem.

Answer (score 0):

If $\alpha$ is any algebraic number with minimal polynomial $f$, then there is a ring homomorphism (indeed a $\mathbb Q$-algebra homomorphism)
$$\mathbb Q[X]\to \mathbb Q[\alpha]\\p(X)\mapsto p(\alpha)$$

called the *evaluation map* (since we are evaluating each polynomial at $\alpha$). Can you calculate the image and kernel of this map? What can you conclude?